# Is it possible to extend JSX / React to allow for custom directives?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, directive

For example, could I define a property like `trackClick={}` so that I can use it in my JSX code like so?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <a href="/foo" trackClick={{ some: "data" }}>bar</a>
  }

}

export default withTracking(MyComponent)

function withTracking(WrappedComponent) {
  // do something here to make `trackClick` possible?
}
```

Comment: Don't use `<a>` directly, use a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

The [react HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) is what you need to understand:

```
function withTracking(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    // this.props.trackClick
    trackHandler => (trackClick) => (e) => {
       // prevent default, since you're using `a` tag
       e.preventDefault()
      // do something with trackClick
    }
    render() {
      const { trackClick, ...rest } = this.props
      return <WrappedComponent 
        onClick={this.trackHandler(trackClick)} 
        {...rest}
      />;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know HOCs, I am asking if I can add custom directives

Comment: See the commented line of code. That is what you can get working with.

Comment: I know what I can do with an HOC, I am still asking if it is possible to create an actual directive

Comment: Now, I'm not sure what you're asking about. You can do with that props what you want.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope, this satisfies your query.